# Declare and use List in java

Tags: java, list

I just touch java, I found if I need to create a new list

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But in my homework, the code is like following. In the function Postering, the parameter is `List<Integer> positions` . Can we put 'ArrayList' there? Or usually we usually put 
List there?

Could someone explain this in a detailed way?

```
static class Posting {
int docID;
List<Integer> positions;
public Posting(int docID, List<Integer> positions) {
  this.docID = docID;
  this.positions = positions;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`List<Integer>` is an *interface*; `ArrayList<Integer>` is a class implementing that interface. You should use `List<Integer>`, because it lets the caller change the implementation - for example, `LinkedList<Integer>`.

This technique for improving flexibility is known as programming to an interface. You can read more about its advantages [in answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/335858).

Comment: Thanks, I did not know the concept for interface before, sicne I always use R and C....

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ArrayList` but it's better to use its interface `List`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `ArrayList` and `List`.

`ArrayList` is an implementation of `List` (such as `LinkedList`, for example).

`List` is an interface, which only describes the methods called by implementations.

By using the interface, the method which call the constructor of your class will be able to use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` (or [an other one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)).